# Computer freezes irregulary

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure

My computer freezes irregulary mostly while watching videos.

- I can reproduce the problem when I remove all hard drives and boot from a memory stick with an linux on it.
- To stop it I have to push the power button for a while. (A short click doesn't help)
- It can take hours for the computer to freeze but when I start watching a video on youtube it will only take minutes to the next crash (But eventually he allways freezes within a day)
- Another confusing thing is that when the computer freezes it takes the router down...

**Computer specifications**

- ***Motherboard*** : ASUS P5N-T Deluxe
- ***Processor***   : Intel Core 2 Quad Q9300 @ 2.50 GHz (4 Cores)
- ***Memory***      : 4096MB
- ***Graphics***    : ASUS Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT 512MB
- ***Monitor***     : ASUS VS247

**Memory**

I've run a `Memtest86` v5.01 and it run 12 passes with zero errors.

[image]

**Processor**

To test my cpu I've run the following [bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2927364/6583901).

```
fulload() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; fulload; read; killall dd
```

All 4 of the cpu cores where a 100% busy for 10 minutes and I experienced no freeze. (But one minute after I've stoped the script)

**Graphics card**

I've bougth another graphic card (`ASUS GT-210 Silent (1GB)`) replaced the old one and still can reproduce the freeze.

**Motherboard**

I searched on the motherboard for damaged capacitors but could not find one.

**Hardware temperature, fan speed, voltage**

`Psensor` is running on the linux and the freezes occur while the temperatures are in the regular area.

[image]

`sensors` tells me the following (almost at the time of the crash).

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +75.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +71.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst = +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst = +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst = +2.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +55.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +56.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:       +53.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:       +49.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:       +1.30 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
+12V Voltage:       +11.58 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
+5V Voltage:         +4.92 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
+3.3V Voltage:       +3.31 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
CPU_FAN FAN Speed:  2428 RPM  (min =  800 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CHA_FAN1 FAN Speed: 1188 RPM  (min =  800 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
PWR FAN FAN Speed:   546 RPM  (min =  800 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CHA_FAN2 FAN Speed: 1066 RPM  (min =  800 RPM, max = 7200 RPM)
CPU Temperature:     +35.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
MB Temperature:      +38.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

Can somebody recommend me what to do next?

---

**EDIT:** I've used another power supply unit (`be quiet BQT E5-450W`) and the freeze still occurs.

**EDIT 2:** I've replaced every part except for the mainboard and the cpu. As I cannot find a motherboard which uses ddr2, pcie3 with an intel lga 755 socket I choose the lazy way and bought a new computer...

Comment: Since this happens without any HDDs, I would look at the GPU, as the possible culprit.  The other other component it could be would be the CPU itself.

Comment: I would follow up on @Ramhound. I would take out the GPU and replace it with another and attempt to watch a video on YouTube with another GPU in it.

Comment: I'll do that as running a cpu or gpu test is allways impossible because the freeze happens before I can start the tests. I'll report back when I know more

Comment: Swap out the GPU, open up YouTube and see if it freezes within minutes again as you describe in the question?

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen I do not have another gpu laying around. I have to get one tomorrow when the stores are open..

Comment: @Dr.Fre - **GPU** not CPU

Comment: misspelled and corrected

Comment: Do your motherboard have a built-in GPU? Try taking out your GPU from the PCI port. And use the built-in VGA/HDMI connector instead? Assuming you have one?

Comment: @AlexanderJohansen no it has not

Comment: @Ramhound can it harm my gpu if any other part is defect? If not I'm going to buy a good one which I can use in my new computer. But if there could be complications I'll buy a cheap one just for testing...

Comment: Its impossible to predict that.

Comment: Are your computer and router connected to the same power bar, UPS, electrical outlet, circuit? If you router **consistently** hangs at the same time I would check carefully for power issues.

Comment: @JensEhrich I had the problem eaven if the computer was pluged in on other places in the same house. One how can I diagnose power issues?

Comment: About the only things that are left are the power supply and motherboard. You could have some bad filter capacitors in either the PSU or MB. I would test with a known good power supply. Additionally, I'd inspect the board for vented capacitors.

Comment: @AtomicFireball I allready searched for cpacitors on the MB which could be damaged but found none. I'm going to buy another PSU to test if it's this part which is damaged. Slowly it gets expensive.

Comment: @Dr.Fre Unfortunately it can be if you don't have spares laying around, or buddies you can bum a component of off for a test. I've got a collection of basic supplies I've kept over the years for troubleshooting purposes. When it gets to these intermittent kind of issues, trial and error is usually how it goes.

Comment: @AtomicFireball I've used another PSU and the freeze still occures.

Comment: I searched on the motherboard for damaged capacitors but could not find one. I had a similar problem once and actually it was a faulty capacitor. You do NOT always see damaged capacitors just by looking at them. I am almost sure this is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When I have that problem. It is 99% of the time because the CPU overheats. It might not show on psensor.
The first thing I always do is removing the heatsync. Cleaning the CPU and the bottom of the heatsync of the thermal compound. And put some new thermal compound on the CPU. Put back the heatsync. And the problem is fixed 99% of the time.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  The temperatures reported by the author do not indicate a problem with their thermal paste nor a cooling problem with the CPU itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I would have add it as a comment if I could. But I need 50 reputation points and I only have 1. It seems that the only thing I can do until I get to 50 is to answer questions. Also, if my suggestion works, it will be an answer. No?

Comment: If you cannot submit comments, then you should wait until you can, to comment on questions.  Edit your answer and remove the commentary.  Go into specific detail on how the author solves his problem.