# How to diagnose infrequent computer freeze on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, freeze

For the past few months I have been experiencing infrequent freezes of my desktop computer. If it happens, the contents of the screen incl. mouse are frozen, I can't use the keyboard to reboot or switch to a virtual console, and SysRq sequences have no effect – the only option is a hard reset via the button on the case.

I'm mainly using Debian 11.6, only occasionally Windows 11 to play games. I've never experienced freezes while gaming, but that may simply be due to the little time I spend doing that.

##### Inconsistent clues:

- The freezes started to happen during the summer, when there was a heat wave here (> 40 °C). So I thought it is an overheating problem, and indeed, with autumn and winter the freezes occurred less frequently – but they haven't stopped entirely. It used to happen every 1 or 2 days, now it happens maybe once a week.
- The freezes often happen while I was watching full-screen video, and sometimes (but not always) a colored pattern appears as if random data were written into video memory. Therefore I thought it might be a problem with the video card. (I have VDPAU installed, therefore programs might use hardware decoding.) However, freezes also occur during normal desktop use.

##### Diagnostics:

- I've looked at the system log after rebooting, but there is no relevant information. The last entries are often minutes earlier, and relate to standard system events. But this might simply mean that the last messages were lost due to the freeze.
- I've used the CPU load test based on `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` from [Computer freezes irregulary](https://superuser.com/questions/1155893/computer-freezes-irregulary), with 7 parallel jobs (CPU is 4-core with hyperthreading). `htop` showed all 8 virtual cores at 100 %, but this did not cause a freeze after ~10 minutes.
- I installed both `memtest86` and `memtest86+` and started the memory test from the boot menu. With both versions, the computer freezes after about a second, but without an error message. See below for screen photos.

  Does this mean that I have faulty memory? I'd have thought that I'd get an error message instead. Moreover, I often manipulate large data files, and never noticed file data corruption. I also occasionally perform scientific calculations that tend to fill main memory, and never experienced a freeze during that either. (I have however regularly brought the system to its knees due to excessive swapping.)

**The only way to trigger a freeze consistently and quickly that I have found is the memory test.**

##### Questions:

- If it is indeed due to faulty memory, how do I figure out which of the four memory modules I have to replace? Or should I always replace all of them?
- I've read under several similar questions that freezes may be due to a defective power supply. I've replaced my power supply about 1½ years ago because the old one died. I originally intended to use the exact same model, which however was no longer manufactured, so I used one with slightly higher specifications. I used the opportunity to thoroughly clean the inside of the case.
- What can I do to better diagnose this problem from the software side? In particular, how can I preserve log messages right up to the freeze? Debian 11 uses systemd logging – is there e.g. a way to send messages to a server instead or additionally?

##### System specifications:

- ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. P8Z77-M Rev 1.xx with SMBIOS 2.7
- American Megatrends Inc. BIOS version 1806
- be quiet! Straight Power 11 750W 750W ATX Black
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
- 256 KiB L1 cache, 1 MiB L2 cache, 8 MiB L3 cache (L3 seems to be disabled, I have no memory of having done that)
- Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset
- 4 modules à 4 GB of Transcend JM1333KLN-8GK DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
- NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1)
- SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series & WDC WD60EFRX, both without SMART errors

The computer is about 10 years old, so it wouldn't be too bad to have to buy a new one. I have made several small upgrades in the meantime (more memory, slightly better CPU, better video card), but none of them are so recent as to explain the freezes.

##### Screen photos of memory test after freeze:

[image: Memtest86]
[image: Memtest86+]

In the second screen, the red "+" continues to blink after the freeze, which indicates that the video card is still functioning.

---

##### Additions:

In response to @Appleoddity's comment, I took out the memory modules. They are sitting tight in their slots, and they including the contacts are clean. When I reinserted them I noticed that sometimes they look inserted but actually aren't properly, fixed by a hard push. But when that happens, I don't get memory errors, but the computer doesn't start at all.

In case it is only one of the modules that has a defect, I put them in one at a time and ran the memory test. However, for each single module, all tests passed without error message and without freeze.

I then put them in in pairs. I'm not sure I got through all 6 combinations, but in all of the several combinations I tried, the computer freezed a few seconds into the memory test.

Finally, I updated the mainboard BIOS (to the latest version, 2203 from 2015-12-18), in the hope that it somehow resolves the problem or at least gives better diagnostics, but without success. I also tried *reducing* the memory clock speed in the BIOS setup, but got the error message that "overclocking" was unsuccessful.

Is there anything else I can try? Should I simply buy entirely new memory modules?

Comment: One thing you should do is reseat the RAM. That means remove it and reinsert it and maybe do that a few times to help seat it more securely and remove oxidation. During the memory test, gently tap on the RAM modules. If you have any problems it could just be a bad connection. Contact cleaner can help. In addition, you can pull the RAM out and run one stick at a time or use different slots to identify bad memory or slots. It’s a methodical process of elimination. It should not freeze during a RAM test.

Comment: Standard question... Did you ever take esd precautions? And no, momentarily touching metal does not count. If not, then you have probably borked one or more chips which have gradually deteriorated.

Comment: @Appleoddity, thanks! Please see the additional information in the edited question.

Comment: possibly an issue with the motherboard/cpu's memory handling/processing, then.